# publish app update without test (and take 5 business day of waiting)

Tags: windows-phone

I just saw the message after I submitted an update for my app

> If your submission needs to be tested, it will take us up to 5 business days to make sure it meets your certification requirements. If not, within a few hours, you can either publish it yourself or it will go live automatically if you chose to automatically publish it. We’ll send you an email once it’s been processed or if we have additional questions.

How can I say that I don't want to be tested. It's a bug fix update that I just sent and I want to publish my app as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry with this message, because it's a default information that is shown after an app is updated. If you only change the price, for example, your app doesn't need be recertified, however if you change other characteristics how the markets, code, ... so it'll be tested again.